# Facebook oauth without pop up

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I tried using the FB.login JavaScript function Facebook provides but it's being affected by pop up blockers. If I want to redirect the user to Facebook instead, how can I do that to get the access token? Or how can I bypass the popup blocker?

Comment: The popup should not get blocked by major browsers in default settings, as long as you call FB.login directly on user interaction (usually meaning on click.) You should not call it without user interaction, or nest it into the callback function of another asynchronous method call - _then_ it is very likely to get blocked. Anyhow, if you want to implement it yourself, go check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: How do I do that involve fb login so that it doesn't get affected by the popup blocker?

Comment: Didn't I just explain that ...?